# Can someone explain Leorio's wager with the prisoner?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In **Season 1 Episode** 10, *Trick x to x the Trick*, Leorio wanted to bet on whether the blue guy was unconscious or not. At the time of the wager the prisoner was down 40-60 against Leorio.

[image]

> PRISONER: Now, it's your turn to wager. What would you like to bet on?
>   LEORIO: Well... I'd like to bet on whether he's really unconscious or not.

Just before Leorio lets go of the blue guy, the prisoner says:

> PRISONER: I bet 40 hours **that he's unconscious**. I'm betting all the time I have left.

Leorio lets go of the blue guy and of course he **wasn't unconscious** yet the prisoner was still awarded with 40 hours!!

[image]
*Prisoner's time on the left, Leorio's time on the right.*

After the prisoner was awarded the 40 hours, she says,

> PRISONER: But now, you only have 20 hours of bargaining chips.

So they definitely made it seem like Leorio lost the wager, but clearly the prisoner did!

**Why didn't the prisoner lose right then and there? Shouldn't that have been the end of the match?**

Comment: Forgive me for asking but did you really watch the whole episode without skipping anything? Because I just re-watched this part and the episode did not happen the way you described it. It adapted everything that I mentioned was in the manga, including the last minute change in wager so there is no reason to be confused in the first place. I'm not sure how you somehow missed this...

Comment: @W.Are I didn't miss the last minute change in wager by the prisoner... I even included it in my post. It seems that the caption was just incorrect and still said *unconscious*. Even for me to make this post with screenshots and dialogue I had to rewatch the scene a few times.

Comment: I see, so it's faulty subtitles. Understandable.

Comment: @Charles just to make the question clearer, is it an official translation or fansub? If it's an official translation, could you mention the publisher? If it's a fansub, could you mention the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some parts. In **Chapter 20** of the manga, when Leorio proposed the bet, the prisoner said:

> Prisoner: All right...**I'll bet 20 hours...that he really is out cold.**

This would mean that *Leorio's bet automatically is that he's not out cold*. When Leorio was about to let go of the guy playing dead, the prisoner changed his mind.

> Leorio: Look, if he yells out while falling...we'll accept that Kurapika's lost on a foul. You'll get the win. That seem fair to you?
>     Prisoner: Yes, quite fair. **But I'd like to change my bet. Let me put 40 hours on him waking up.**

So, Leorio's bet was changed to the guy not waking up due to this last minute proposition. Therefore, he lost.

Comment: To support this answer, the prisoner actually said 「彼が本当に**気絶していない**方に40時間」which is literally translated to "*not* *un*conscious" (yeah, it's a double negative).